# Is there a name for a group action such that stabilizers are never the group itself?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group and $X$ a set with an action $G\times X\to X$. Is there a name for an action with property that for all $x\in X$ the stabilizer is a *proper* subgroup, i.e. $G_x\neq G$? In other words the orbits $Gx$ are always non-trivial; i.e. $Gx\neq x$. In particular I'm interested in a group action which is faithful and furthermore satisfies the above property.

Comment: I have heard "fixed-point-free"

Comment: I think (and wikipedia agrees) that fixed-point free means $G_x={e}$ is trivial for all $x\in X$. This is not the case here necessarily. This is kinda "trivial-orbit-free" or something.

Comment: No, I think the term is "fixed point free." A fixed point is a point with stabilizer $G$ by definition.

Comment: @Hamed "$G_x=e$ for all $x$" is called a *free action*.

Comment: Some people say "an action without a global fixed point" to avoid the confusion, but "fixed point free" is more concise.

Comment: Thank you all... Fixed-point free it is. My issue was that wikipedia uses free and fixed-point free synonymously. This all depends I guess on what you'll call a fixed point. If you call $x\in X$ which is fixed by *some* $g\in G$ a fixed point, then free and fixed-point free are the same. If you define a fixed point as $x\in X$ which is fixed by *all* $G$, then what I need is fixed-point free exactly.